# Casting from int* to char* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

- line 1 prints 'X'
- line 2 prints 'c'
- line 3 prints 11
- line 4 prints 5.

I   understand these lines but why does

- line 5 print 20

?

Should it not print   11 instead of 20 since line 1 and 2 print 'X' and 'c'.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int arr[] = {88, 20, 30, 40, 50, 99};
int *ptr1 = arr;
int *ptr2 = arr + 5;
cout<<(char*)ptr1<<endl;//line 1
cout<<(char*)ptr2<<endl;//line2
cout<<('c'-'X')<<endl;//line3
cout<<ptr2-ptr1<<endl;//line4
cout<<(char*)ptr2-(char*)ptr1<<endl;//line5

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What `int *ptr2 ... cout<<(char*)ptr2` ?!

Comment: 5 elements, 4 bytes each, 5*4 = 20.  so it prints 20!

Comment: It should be possible to vote up fitting names :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the environment where the program was compiled `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`. That is each object of type int occupies 4 bytes (characters). Between ptr2 and ptr1 there are 5 integers. The difference of two pointers that point to elements of the same array is the number of elements between them.
It is so-called pointer arithmetic. Thus ptr2 - ptr1 gives 5. But if you will cast these pointers to type `char *` then between these pointers there are `5 * sizeof( int )` characters that is equal to 20.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `(char*)ptr2-(char*)ptr1` is the difference of addresses. Then `5*sizeof(int) = 20` in your (I guess) 32 bits platform.

Comment: where did you get 32 bit platform from?

Comment: Because of `int` is platform dependant.

Comment: It depends on various thing: eg. in unix world you can have different standards:  ILP64 with `int` 64bits long, LP64 and LLP64 with `int` 32 bits long. Finally what I mean is that is not granted that a 8/16/64 bits platform has `sizeof(int) = 4`. Btw I don't understand who downvote my answer....

Answer (score 1):

TO get the output what you are expecting use:

`(char)*ptr2-(char)*ptr1`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is absolutely correct let me explain your anwer step by step according to code:

```
cout<<(char*)ptr1<<endl;//line1
```

Since ptr1 = arr, therefore first char is 88 and thus printed X

```
cout<<(char*)ptr2<<endl;//line2
```

Since ptr1 = arr +5, therefore fifth char is 99 and thus printed c

```
cout<<('c'-'X')<<endl;//line3
```

Since the value of 'c' =99 and 'X' = 88 thus answer is 11

```
cout<<ptr2-ptr1<<endl;//line4
```

Since the arr is an array and distance between 5th and 0th element 5-0 = 5

```
cout<<(char*)ptr2-(char*)ptr1<<endl;//line5
```

What here happens there you are subtracting two address and answer is provided as differance of two addresss, for instance

```
 (char *)ptr1 --- Address = 10
 (char *)ptr2 --- Address = 30
```

and if we subtract both then 30-10=20. Why it is 20 as it depends on the sizeof void *

```
32 bit sizeof void* = 4
64 bit sizeof void* = 8
```

Thus on 32 bit system answer would be 4*5=20 and on 64 bit system it would be 8*5=40

Comment: "*...  on 64 bit system it would be 8*5=40*" No, on 64bit with the size of an `int` being 4 you'd still get 20.

Comment: @alk Memory or Casting are done through Void Pointer and Not through Int. The size of int my be 4 bytes but because of casting through void pointer the addressess allocated at distance of 8 bytes. Even if the size of int is 4, left bytes are padded

Comment: This is basic pointer arithmetic (which is platform independed) : The pointer difference in bytes is `<distance counted by elements the pointers point to> * sizeof(<what type the pointers point to>)`, no matter what size the pointers/addresses have. Its the same for 16bit, 32bit, 64bit, ...

Comment: Check on 64 bit what would be the sizeof(char *); size of pointer is dependent on bits of processor

Comment: Yes, the size of a pointer is different. But for the OP's line 5 this does not matter.

Comment: It matters try to comple on 64 bit. I am 101% sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71753/discussion-between-vineet1982-and-alk).

Answer (score 0):

The first ptr1 points to these bytes in memory: 88,0,0,0 - which is the first index in array.
The ptr2 points to these bytes in memory: 99,0,0,0.
So the first two lines are outputting two null terminated strings: X and c.

The third line is outputting the difference between chars c and X, which is int value.

The fourth value is difference between two pointers in respect to on what these pointers are pointing to (relative position in array). This is an int number.

The last is cast to char*, where char is 1 byte, which makes it 4 times smaller then int (int is 4 bytes big). So the difference is (array position difference) * (size of int) = 5 * 4 = 20. This value is int so that is why you see number 20.

Try to change all those ints in to char and see the difference:

```
char arr[] = { 88, 20, 30, 40, 50, 99 };
char *ptr1 = arr;
char *ptr2 = arr + 5;
```

Suddenly these first two lines are no longer one chars, because there is no longer the 0 terminator for (char*) strings.

X¶▲(2c╠╠╠╠╠╠╬H@▼ñ¸4
c╠╠╠╠╠╠╬H@▼ñ¸4
11
5
5

This will vary between debug and release.